# Getting the ID of a user, after searching for his/her name in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So when a user completes the quiz, he/she fills out his/her name and email. On submit I need to create the user in the User db, as well as store the individuals answers in a related Answer db. So obviously for the contact_id field I need to input the id for the Contact where :name => params[:name]. When I tack on .id at the end of the statement I get "no method error id". When I am in the view however, contact.id works fine. I am sure this is a cinch problem, but I need help. Thanks

```
    def submit
    t = Contact.new
    t.name = params[:name]
    t.email = params[:email]
    t.save
    params.each do |key, value|
         x = Answer.new
         x.month = 1
         x.question = key.to_i
         x.answer = value
         x.contact_id = Contact.where(:name => params[:name])
         x.save
    end
    redirect_to('/')
  end
```

UPDATE: I have got things to work by using x.contact_id = Contact.last.id

Last because we had just created a new user .2ms ago, so it is most likely the user we want. Is this a bad method?

UPDATE: New fail code I am trying to work with.

```
  def submit
t = Contact.new
t.name = params[:name]
t.email = params[:email]
t.save
params.each do |key, value|
   # target groups using regular expressions

   if (key.to_s[/[0-9]/])
     s = Contact.where({:name => params[:name]})
     x = Answer.new
     x.month = 1
     x.question = key.to_i
     x.answer = value
     x.contact_id = s.id
     x.save
   end
end
redirect_to('/')
```

end

UDATE: This controller code is working for me now.

```
    class MonthOneController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end
  def submit
    t = Contact.new
    t.name = params[:name]
    t.email = params[:email]
    params.each do |key, value|
       # target groups using regular expressions       
       if (key.to_s[/[0-9]/])
         t.answers.build(:month => 1, :question => key.to_i, :answer => value)
       end
    end
    t.save
    redirect_to('/')
  end
end
```

I needed to create a row for each question and answer, and there were multiple passed in through params[]. They also come in like this "1" : "false", "2" : "e" etc. So the regexp just gives me those versus the persons email address and name.

Here is my hideous form code. I did this first, and am learning along the way.

```
    <%= form_tag("/MonthOne", :method => "get") do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Question") %><br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("1", :a) %>Customer Scenario Tool<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("1", :b) %>Videos<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("1", :c) %>Sales Preview<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("1", :d) %>Sales Rep Mailer<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("1", :e) %>Unsolicited Proposal<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "question 1") %><br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("2", :true) %>True<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("2", :false) %>True<br />

  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "question 2:") %><br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("3", :a) %>answer 1<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("3", :b) %>answer 2<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("3", :c) %>answer 3<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("3", :d) %>answer 4<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("3", :e) %>answer 5<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "question 3") %><br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("4", :a) %>1,500<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("4", :b) %>10,000<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("4", :c) %>15,000<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("4", :d) %>30,000<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "question 4") %><br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("5", :a) %>answer 1<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("5", :b) %>answer 2<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("5", :c) %>answer 3<br />
    <%= radio_button_tag("5", :d) %>answer 4<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    Name: <%= text_field_tag(:name) %><br />
    Email: <%= text_field_tag(:email) %> <br />
  </p>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to change this using Form for and the accepts_nested_attributes but I could not get passed the errors. Partly because the controller and views were made by me, and do not follow rails conventions. So when form_for was building the form, it could not find contact_path etc.

Comment: using `last` is bad because if you go multithreaded or with concurrent use on your db, you can't be sure the last `Contact` inserted will be the right one. Does your `Answer` model `belong_to :contact` ? if so, just use `t.answers.build` as described in [RoR association guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference). Anyway, just ask if you need more details

Comment: Ok, sweet. My Answer model does belong to contact. Going to figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Holy Cow! That is some serious magic. It works just like you said, except it is inserting 'nil' in the answer columns. I have to look into getting the right params into it. Thanks

Comment: you may need to `save` your `Contact` object before being able to fiddle with associated objects. There are two ways to get around this: use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), or wrap the whole process in a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it, when I need to iterate over the params for the ones I need. Isn't there a simple way to just look up the newly made Contacts name, then get the id of that and insert into the Answer table? ahhh... but what if their are multiple names... could search by email address.

Comment: ok, this is so confusing, i don't quite understand what you're up to.

Comment: A big reason to use rails is to use standards and 'convention over configuration' (which mostly means if you name things according to standards, rails 'magic' will save you writing much of the code).  The zombies videos (wierd name but just google) are amazing lessons and relatively cheap at about $50 each. Compared to other paid stuff was good value for me.

Comment: Yes Rails for zombies taught me the most, being able to do the quizzes right in the browser is a phenominal way to learn. The problem is that the relationship chapter does not cover the creation of a new zombie AND a new tweet at the same time. In that situation you have the luxury of knowing the zombie's id that you are working with, and are able to manipulate data that way. Here I am creating a new contact, and submitting his answers into the Answer table at the same time. So I was confused about the foreign key. But iterating and using .build solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to hack a solution for a problem that rails has a pretty decent solution for.
**accepts_nested_attributes_for** in your model, together with **fields_for** in view should be able to make this fairly easy... as cake actually :-P

Ryan Bates og railscasts has a couple of episodes covering the subject.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

The link m_x gave you also has some explanation of the same.

His example is even fairly close to what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Excellent advice, just what I would do.

Comment: Yes. I have been watching those exact casts on the matter. I am going to post my form and the updated code. I was not able to get the form_for working for me, because at the start of this I did not go the "rails way". It's a pain because I do not get that nice validation that Ryan also covers. Hopefully when I update my code you can help me refactor a bit :)

Comment: That is also my biggest problem when using rails. There are alot of railsian ways of doing things. Slowly, very slowly do I pick them up. Oftentimes leading to super quick rewrites of stuff that had taken me a long time to figure out... railscasts I think is a great way to discover them though. I just need to discover some more resources like it.